# Imposibilidad de agregar JMenuBar con mi planteamiento usando GridBagLayout

Tags: java, formularios, java-swing, jframe

Estoy tratando de agregar una barra de menú JMenuBar usando el organizador GridBagLayout, y me veo incapacitado para ello.

Alguien me podria dar una explicación de como hacerlo ?

TEngo un ejercicio básico en el que he agregado label y botones para hacer pruebas. Hasta ahí, no tengo problemas, pero a la hora de agregar la barra de menús, me pierdo.

Este es mi código:

```
public class ClaseGridBagLayout extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    GridBagLayout admin = new GridBagLayout();
    GridBagConstraints subLayout;
    

    //instancio el menú
    JMenuBar miMenu;
        JMenu mArchivo;
            JMenuItem iCopiar;
            JMenuItem iPegar;
        JMenu mAyuda;
            JMenuItem iAyuda;

    //instancio los label del ejercicio
    JLabel lblTitulo;
    JLabel lblFila1Dos;
    JLabel lblFila2Uno;
    JLabel lblFila2Tres;
    JLabel lblFila3Dos;

    //instancio los botones del ejercicio
    JButton btnFila1Uno;
    JButton btnFila1tres;
    JButton btnFila2Dos;
    JButton btnFila3Uno;
    JButton btnFila3Tres;

    JButton btnCerrar;

    //cnstructor de la clase
    public ClaseGridBagLayout(){
        super(" La clase ClaseGridBagLayout");
    
        //creo los distintos métodos
        metodoCargarConfiguracion();       
        metodoCargarIconos();        
        metodoCargarMenu();        
        metodoCargarComponentesPasivos();        
        metodoCargarComponentesActivos();
    
        //le doy la medida necesaria para los elemtos que se carguen
        pack();
        //lo hago visible
        setVisible(true);
    }

    //como ejemplo le doy función al botón cerrar
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == btnCerrar){
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    //aquí cargo la configuración general con el controlador GridBagLayout
    private void metodoCargarConfiguracion() {
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    
        //creo el gestor para las posiciones en pantalla
        subLayout = new GridBagConstraints();
    
        setLookAndFeel();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private void metodoCargarIconos() {
    
    }

    //cargo label y los posiciono por la ventana
    private void metodoCargarComponentesPasivos() {
    
        lblTitulo = new JLabel("Título");
        subLayout.gridx = 0;
        subLayout.gridy = 1;
        subLayout.weightx = 1;
        subLayout.weighty = 1;
        this.getContentPane().add(lblTitulo, subLayout);
    
        lblFila1Dos = new JLabel("1 - 2");
        subLayout.gridx = 2;
        subLayout.gridy = 2;
        subLayout.weightx = 1;
        subLayout.weighty = 1;
        this.getContentPane().add(lblFila1Dos, subLayout);
    
        lblFila2Uno = new JLabel("2 - 1");
        subLayout.gridx = 1;
        subLayout.gridy = 3;
        subLayout.weightx = 1;
        subLayout.weighty = 1;
        this.getContentPane().add(lblFila2Uno, subLayout);
    
        lblFila2Tres = new JLabel("2 - 3");
        subLayout.gridx = 3;
        subLayout.gridy = 3;
        subLayout.weightx = 1;
        subLayout.weighty = 1;
        this.getContentPane().add(lblFila2Tres, subLayout);
    
        lblFila3Dos = new JLabel("3 - 2");
        subLayout.gridx = 2;
        subLayout.gridy = 4;
        subLayout.weightx = 1;
        subLayout.weighty = 1;
        this.getContentPane().add(lblFila3Dos, subLayout);
    }

    //cargo botones y los posiciono por la ventana
    private void metodoCargarComponentesActivos() {
    
        btnFila1Uno = new JButton("1 - 1");
        subLayout.gridx = 1;
        subLayout.gridy = 5;
        subLayout.weightx = 1;
        subLayout.weighty = 1;
        this.getContentPane().add(btnFila1Uno, subLayout);
    
        btnFila1tres = new JButton("1 - 3");
        subLayout.gridx = 3;
        subLayout.gridy = 5;
        subLayout.weightx = 1;
        subLayout.weighty = 1;
        this.getContentPane().add(btnFila1tres, subLayout);
    
        btnFila2Dos = new JButton("2 - 2");
        subLayout.gridx = 2;
        subLayout.gridy = 6;
        subLayout.weightx = 1;
        subLayout.weighty = 1;
        this.getContentPane().add(btnFila2Dos, subLayout);
    
        btnFila3Uno = new JButton("3 - 1");
        subLayout.gridx = 1;
        subLayout.gridy = 7;
        subLayout.weightx = 1;
        subLayout.weighty = 1;
        this.getContentPane().add(btnFila3Uno, subLayout);
    
        btnFila3Tres = new JButton("3 - 3");
        subLayout.gridx = 3;
        subLayout.gridy = 7;
        subLayout.weightx = 1;
        subLayout.weighty = 1;
        this.getContentPane().add(btnFila3Tres, subLayout);
    
        btnCerrar = new JButton("Cerrar");
        btnCerrar.addActionListener(this);
        subLayout.gridx = 2;
        subLayout.gridy = 8;
        subLayout.weightx = 1;
        subLayout.weighty = 1;
        this.getContentPane().add(btnCerrar, subLayout);

    }

    //método principal
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ClaseGridBagLayout miClase = new ClaseGridBagLayout();
    }

    //método sin función con el diseño por defecto
    private void setLookAndFeel() {
        try{
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("");
        }
        catch (Exception e){
        
        }
    }

    //aquí intento cargar el menú sin éxito
    private void metodoCargarMenu() {
    
        //creo la barra de menús
        miMenu = new JMenuBar();
    
        //creo el menú y sus item
        mArchivo = new JMenu();
            iCopiar = new JMenuItem();
            iPegar = new JMenuItem();
        mAyuda = new JMenu();
            iAyuda = new JMenuItem();
    
    
        //agrego el menú a la barra
        miMenu.add(mArchivo);
        miMenu.add(mAyuda);

        //agrego los item al menú
        mArchivo.add(iCopiar);
        mArchivo.add(iPegar);
        mAyuda.add(iAyuda);
    
        //agrego la barra al panel principal, pero no se como agregarlo al constraint del GridBagLayout. La verdad, no tengo idea de como se ha de hacer
        this.setJMenuBar(miMenu);
        subLayout.gridx = 0;
        subLayout.gridy = 0;
        subLayout.weightx = 1;
        subLayout.weighty = 1;
        this.getContentPane().add(miMenu, subLayout);

    }
}
```

La verdad que ando un poco perdido con éste tema de la barra, diferentes pruebas y ninguna funciona.

Lo he intentado agregando un JPanel, y una layout dentro del JPanel, agregando la barra al layout, pero tampoco lo logro.

```
//creo el panel
JPanel fila1 = new JPanel();
//creo el gestor de la ventana del panel
GridLayout f1 = new GridLayout(2, 1);

//agrego el menú al gestor del panel
fila1.add(miMenu);
//agrego el gestor al panel
fila1.setLayout(f1);
//agrego el panel al panel principal GridBagLayout gestionado por el constraint subLayout;
this.getContentPane().add(fila1, subLayout);
```

Alguien me podría dar luz al respecto ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El JMenu Bar no debe agregarse al JPanel, debe agregarse al JFrame
this.setJMenuBar(miMenu);

Mira este [Enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49510303/positioning-buttons-below-menu-bar-with-gridbaglayout) te va a ayudar bastante.

Answer (score 1):

Vale

Después de mirar el enlace que me propuso Jua'n Albert'o y de buscar y rebuscar, he podido agregar el menú cambiando un poco la configuración inicial

Ahora me ha quedado así:

```
//en el método constructor
public PresupuestoBoda(){
    //damos título al JFrame
    super("Elaboración de presupuesto de Boda");
    //y cargamos como administrador del Layout el GridBagLayout
    this.getContentPane().setLayout (new GridBagLayout()); 

    //llamamos al método que carga la configuración
    metodoCargarConfiguracion();
    
    //llamamos al método que carga el menú
    metodoCargarMenu();
    
    //situamos el JFrame en la pantalla y le damos las dimensiones deseadas
    setBounds(50, 50, 1000, 700);
    //hacemos el JFrame visible
    setVisible(true);
}

//método que carga la configuración
private void metodoCargarConfiguracion() {
    
    //instanciamos el JPanel raiz
    panelRaiz = new JPanel();
    //instanciamos el gestor del layout
    miLayout = new GridBagLayout();
    //instanciamos el constraint que situará los componentes en el JFrame
    subLayout = new GridBagConstraints();

    //agregamos el gestor al JFrame
    panelRaiz.setLayout(miLayout);
    this.setContentPane(panelRaiz);
    
    setLookAndfeel();
    //hacemos que no se pueda cambiar el tamaño del JFrame
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

//método que carga el menú
private void metodoCargarMenu() {
    //creamos la barra de menú
    miMenu = new JMenuBar();
        //creamos los elemntos del menú y sus item
        mNovios = new JMenu("Novios");
            iNovio = new JMenuItem("Novio");
            iNovia = new JMenuItem("Novia");
            iInvitados = new JMenuItem("Invitados");
            iFecha = new JMenuItem("Fecha");
        mMenu = new JMenu("Menú");
            iSopa = new JMenuItem("Sopa o Crema");
            iAperitivo = new JMenuItem("Aperitivo");
            iPescado = new JMenuItem("Pescado");
            iCarne = new JMenuItem("Carne");
            iPostre = new JMenuItem("Postre");
        mExtras = new JMenu("Extras y Servicios");
            iExtras = new JMenuItem("Extras");
            iServicios = new JMenuItem("Servicios");
            iImpresion = new JMenuItem("Impresión");
        mAyuda = new JMenu("Ayuda");    
            iAyuda = new JMenuItem("Ayuda");
            iProgramacion = new JMenuItem("Programador");

    //los vamos agregando unos a otros
    miMenu.add(mNovios);
        mNovios.add(iNovio);
        mNovios.add(iNovia);
        mNovios.add(iInvitados);
        mNovios.add(iFecha);
    miMenu.add(mMenu);
        mMenu.add(iSopa);
        mMenu.add(iAperitivo);
        mMenu.add(iPescado);
        mMenu.add(iCarne);
        mMenu.add(iPostre);
    miMenu.add(mExtras);
        mExtras.add(iExtras);
        mExtras.add(iServicios);
        mExtras.add(iImpresion);
    miMenu.add(mAyuda);
        mAyuda.add(iAyuda);
        mAyuda.add(iProgramacion);

    //agregamos la barra al JFrame como bien decía Jua'n Albert'o en su comentario y no al gestor del layout
    this.setJMenuBar(miMenu);
}
```