# Posicionar correctamente un panel dentro de otro

Tags: java, java-swing, jpanel, java-awt, posicionamiento

¿Alguien podría echarme una mano con un pequeño problema al posicionar correctamente
dos paneles?

Lo que tengo actualmente es esto:

[image: Problema actual]

Lo que quiero conseguir es que el menú que está dentro del panel principal aparezca arriba a la izquierda y el segundo panel un poco más abajo y centrado, pero no tengo claro cómo conseguirlo con la configuración actual:

El código de los componentes:

```
    JFrame ventana = new JFrame();
    ventana.setTitle("Teléfono Prepago");
    ventana.setSize(400,300);
    ventana.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    ventana.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    ventana.setResizable(true);
    
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT,5, 20));
    panel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLUE));


    JPanel panel_elementos = new JPanel((new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 1000, 20)));
    panel_elementos.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,300));
    panel_elementos.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
    panel_elementos.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(300, 300));;
    panel_elementos.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.red));


    configuracion.add(nm);
    configuracion.add(el);
    configuracion.add(cmm);
    barra.add(configuracion);
    panel_elementos.add(llamar);
    panel_elementos.add(colgar);
    panel_elementos.add(recargar);
    panel_elementos.add(texto_saldo);
    panel_elementos.add(cuadro_texto);
    panel.add(barra);
    panel.add(panel_elementos);
    ventana.add(panel);
    ventana.setVisible(true);


    Dimension tamano_favorito = new Dimension(100, 30);

    JMenuBar barra = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu configuracion = new JMenu("Config");
    JMenuItem nm = new JMenuItem("Número de Móvil");
    JMenuItem el = new JMenuItem("Establec. llamda");
    JMenuItem cmm = new JMenuItem("Coste Minuto Llamada");

    JButton llamar = new JButton("llamar");
    llamar.setMaximumSize(tamano_favorito);
    llamar.setPreferredSize(tamano_favorito);

    JButton colgar = new JButton("colgar");
    colgar.setMaximumSize(tamano_favorito);
    colgar.setPreferredSize(tamano_favorito);

    JButton recargar = new JButton("Recargar");
    recargar.setMaximumSize(tamano_favorito);
    recargar.setPreferredSize(tamano_favorito);

    JLabel texto_saldo = new JLabel("saldo");

    JTextField cuadro_texto = new JTextField();
    cuadro_texto.setMaximumSize(tamano_favorito);
    cuadro_texto.setPreferredSize(tamano_favorito);
    cuadro_texto.setMinimumSize(tamano_favorito);
```

Answer (score 1):

Tuve esa misma duda y/o problema no hace mucho

Me contestaron que los menús no pueden añadirse a los paneles, sino en el contenedor principal, en tu caso en el JFrame ventana. Lo haces con la instrucción:

```
ventana.getContentPane().add(barra, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

En éste caso lo agrego con un gestor BorderLayout y la envío al norte del mismo.

Ésta fue mi pregunta y las respuestas que obtuve

[Consulta sobre menú](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/502968/imposibilidad-de-agregar-jmenubar-con-mi-planteamiento-usando-gridbaglayout/504888#504888)

Este es mi ejemplo completo aobre tu código algo modificado :

```
public class MenuEjemplo extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    //frame
    JFrame ventana;

    //paneles
    JPanel panel;
    JPanel panel_elementos;

    //dimension
    Dimension tamano_favorito;

    //menu
    JMenuBar barra;
        JMenu configuracion;
            JMenuItem nm;
            JMenuItem el;
            JMenuItem cmm;
        
    //botones
    JButton llamar;
    JButton colgar;
    JButton recargar;

    //label y texto
    JLabel texto_saldo;
    JTextField cuadro_texto;

    //constructor
    public MenuEjemplo(){
        super("Teléfono Prepago");
    
        //vamos llamando a los métodos
        metodoCargarConfiguracion();
    
        metodoCargarMenu();
    
        metodoCargarComponentesPasivos();
    
        metodoCargarComponenetesActivos();
    
        metodoCargarPanel();
    
        metodoCargarPanelElementos();
    
        //hacemos el Frame visible
        ventana.setVisible(true);
        //le damos el tamaño
        ventana.setSize(400,450);
    }

    //método main
    public static void main(String[] args){
        //instanciamos la clase
        MenuEjemplo miEjemplo = new MenuEjemplo();
    }

    //eventos de los botones
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        if (ae.getSource() == llamar){
        
        }
        else if (ae.getSource() == colgar){
        
        }
        else if (ae.getSource() == recargar){
        
        }
    
        if (ae.getActionCommand().equals("llamar")){
        
        }
        else if (ae.getActionCommand().equals("colgar")){
        
        }
        else if (ae.getActionCommand().equals("recargar")){
        
        }
    }

    //método para cargar a configuración del Frame
    private void metodoCargarConfiguracion() {
        ventana = new JFrame();
    
        //usamos el gestor BorderLayout
        BorderLayout admin = new BorderLayout();
        //Cargamos el gestor
        ventana.setLayout(admin);
    
        //configuramos el tamaño de la dimensión personalizada
        tamano_favorito = new Dimension(100, 30);
    
        //cargamos la ventana en el centro de la pantalla
        ventana.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        ventana.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        ventana.setResizable(true);
    }

    //método para cargar label y cuadros de texto
    private void metodoCargarComponentesPasivos() {
        texto_saldo = new JLabel("saldo");

        cuadro_texto = new JTextField();
        cuadro_texto.setMaximumSize(tamano_favorito);
        cuadro_texto.setPreferredSize(tamano_favorito);
        cuadro_texto.setMinimumSize(tamano_favorito);
    }

    //método para cargar los botones
    private void metodoCargarComponenetesActivos() {
        llamar = new JButton("llamar");
        llamar.setMaximumSize(tamano_favorito);
        llamar.setPreferredSize(tamano_favorito);
        llamar.addActionListener(this);
        llamar.setActionCommand("llamar");

        colgar = new JButton("colgar");
        colgar.setMaximumSize(tamano_favorito);
        colgar.setPreferredSize(tamano_favorito);
        colgar.addActionListener(this);
        llamar.setActionCommand("Colgar");

        recargar = new JButton("Recargar");
        recargar.setMaximumSize(tamano_favorito);
        recargar.setPreferredSize(tamano_favorito);
        recargar.addActionListener(this);
        llamar.setActionCommand("Recargar");
    }

    //método para cargar el menú
    private void metodoCargarMenu() {
        barra = new JMenuBar();
            configuracion = new JMenu("Config");
                nm = new JMenuItem("Número de Móvil");
                nm.addActionListener(this);
                el = new JMenuItem("Establec. llamda");
                el.addActionListener(this);
                cmm = new JMenuItem("Coste Minuto Llamada");
                cmm.addActionListener(this);
            
        configuracion.add(nm);
        configuracion.add(el);
        configuracion.add(cmm);
    
        barra.add(configuracion);
        //añadimos el menú al Frame usando el gestor y lo situamos al norte
        ventana.getContentPane().add(barra, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }

    //método para cargar el Panel panel
    private void metodoCargarPanel() {
        panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT,40, 40));
        panel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLUE));
    
        ventana.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    //método para cargar el Panel panel elementos
    private void metodoCargarPanelElementos() {
        panel_elementos = new JPanel((new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 1000, 20)));
        panel_elementos.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,300));
        panel_elementos.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        panel_elementos.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(300, 300));;
        panel_elementos.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.red));
    
        panel_elementos.add(llamar);
        panel_elementos.add(colgar);
        panel_elementos.add(recargar);
        panel_elementos.add(texto_saldo);
        panel_elementos.add(cuadro_texto);
    
        panel.add(panel_elementos);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Gracias. He conseguido que me quedara como yo quería, aunque he seguido un camino distinto al que propones.

Básicamente, en lugar de poner un panel dentro de otro, ahora hay dos paneles dentro de la ventana y se posicionan siguiendo las reglas del "BorderLayout".

Un panel para el menú y otro panel para el resto de componentes. Uno en la zona norte y otro en la zona central.

Ambos paneles utilizan "FlowLayout" cada uno con una alineación distinta.